# Реакция только при клике на внешнем li

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть проблема:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
....same blocks
</ul>
```

Когда я нажимаю на внешний li он получает класс "active". Жму еще раз - класс пропадает. Но когда я жму на внутренний li, то класс "active" все равно уходит. Помогите, как сделать так, чтобы они реагировали на клики независимо друг от друга?

JS

```
   $('.nav-cats li').click(function(){

        if($(this).hasClass("active"))
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        else
            $(this).addClass("active");
    });
```

HTML

```
<ul class="nav-cats">
        <a href="#"><li>
            Home<br/><span class="quant-of-cats">(652547)</span>
            <ul>
                <a href="#">
                    <li>Subcat</li>
                </a>
            </ul>
        </li></a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как то так: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/18mgskdf/

HTML:

```
<ul class='test'>
    <li>Top level
        <ul>
            <li>Second level</li>
            <li>Second level</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Top level
        <ul>
            <li>Second level</li>
            <li>Second level</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.active {
    background: #eee;
}
.active .active {
    background: #f00;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.test').find('li').on('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // запрещает событию подниматься выше
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, сработало!